# Avoiding "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI" or catch-all controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

What is the best way to avoid the following warnings?

```
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [......]
```

I tried to add a catch-all controller as follows:

```
@Controller
class CatchAllController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public ResponseEntity<?> catchAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

But for some reason, static content (i.e. `src/main/resources/static/`) is also caught by the controller and therefore is not accessible.

On the other hand, I don't want these warnings to appear in the logs since clients may access random URI and I don't want to be notified about it.

Answer (score 2):

> On the other hand, I don't want these warnings to appear in the logs
>   since clients may access random URI and I don't want to be notified
>   about it.

Then simply disable the logger that logs these warnings.

As of [Spring 5.1.4.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#PAGE_NOT_FOUND_LOG_CATEGORY), these are logged from the `DispatcherServlet` through these members

```
/** Log category to use when no mapped handler is found for a request. */
public static final String PAGE_NOT_FOUND_LOG_CATEGORY = "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound";

/** Additional logger to use when no mapped handler is found for a request. */
protected static final Log pageNotFoundLogger = LogFactory.getLog(PAGE_NOT_FOUND_LOG_CATEGORY);
```

With Logback, you'd declare something like

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound" level="ERROR">
   ...
</logger>
```

Similarly, with log4j2, you'd do

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound" level="ERROR">
   ...
</Logger>
```

Comment: Yes - increasing the level of the logger is always a solution, but I supposed that if Spring decided to WARN in this case, there may be a reason. Maybe it's a good practice to cover all possible URIs? If yes, how can I do that without getting into the issue I described in the question?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache You can look at registering your own `HandlerMapping` last to handle all previously unhandled requests.